# Validation through Try-Catch block C#

Tags: c#, validation

I am a beginner at C# and I am trying to use a 'Try and catch' block to act as a validation when the user inputs something. It works when the user enters an invalid input the first time but the system crashes when the user enters an invalid input the second time.

I tried to get through this problem by creating a bool variable which is set true until user inputs correct input but have not been very successful.

The main problem is I don't know how to make the system set the bool variable to false when the user inputs a correct input

C# Code:

```
while (invalidInput == true)
{
    try
    {
        {
            Console.Write("Landscape Size: ");
            LandscapeSize = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Initial number of warrens: ");
            InitialWarrenCount = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Initial number of foxes: ");
            InitialFoxCount = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Randomness variability (percent): ");
            Variability = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            FixedInitialLocations = false;
        }
        Sim = new Simulation(LandscapeSize, InitialWarrenCount, InitialFoxCount, Variability, FixedInitialLocations);
    }
    catch
    {
        Console.WriteLine("invalid input!");
        LandscapeSize = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        InitialWarrenCount = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        InitialFoxCount = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Variability = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        invalidInput = true;
    }
    invalidInput = false;
}
```

Also, I am new to stack overflow so sorry if I make any mistakes.

So my question is what am I doing wrong? Thank you

Comment: This is a very bad idea, but regardless, your bug is setting `invalidInput = false;` after the loop. It must be at the end of the `try`

Comment: Why is it a bad idea? is there a more efficient and easier way? and thank you

Comment: `int.TryParse` is preferable both  because it is faster, and because exceptions should not be used for control flow.

Comment: Btw, I did what you suggested and it worked when I input incorrect first time, but system crashed when I did it a second time?

Comment: Try and catch statements are normally used for catching errors that need to be recovered from, none existing file handles and such or write failure permissions. So things that generate an exception on failure. Your validation of the input should just be handled in the normal code. Using a invalidInput boolean is oke, just don't wrap it in a try/catch block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem your having is that *invalidInput* is set to false every time the loop is executed - independent of the try-catch block. Move it to the end of the try-block instead, this way you will ensure that all the code in the try-block does not throw an error before you set the flag. However, since exceptions rarely are used for control-flow you should probably use some kind of control-statement like an *if-statement*.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to set `invalidInput` to `false` at the end of the `try block`.

However, use `int.TryParse` to control flow instead of exceptions.

```
int landscapeSize;

Console.Write("Landscape Size: ");
while(!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out landscapeSize))
{
    Console.Write("Invalid input. Enter landscape size: ");
}
```

Do this for all your inputs.

Comment: Same as mine but even shorter (I know probably written at the same time). I have removed my answer :D